# What is the product formed in the reaction of dimedone and benzaldehyde?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, aldol-reaction

I'm having a hard time deducing the structure of the product formed when dimedone and benzaldehyde react in the presence of catalytic piperidine. I think that a Knoevenagel reaction will get me to this product:

[image: 2-[hydroxy(phenyl)methyl]-5,5-dimethylcyclohexane-1,3-dione]

but the answer says that the product has a molar mass of 368 g/mol. The product above is only 246 g/mol. What else can have occurred?

Comment: You did an aldol-type reaction. The Knoevenagel condensation goes further. What does condensation mean? There is no mention of stoichiometry. Finally, think Michael reaction.

Answer (score 1):

This  image  should  help  you:

[image]

Comment: The conditions in this reaction are clearly not the same as those stipulated in the question. What makes you think that the product will be the same? It probably *is*, but this line of reasoning is highly unclear.